# Does this check sum system have a name?

Tags: math, checksum

Given the number 654 the check sum is 7.

The check sum is calculated by splitting the numbers into individual digits, and calculating the bitwise XOR sum for all digits.

A limitation is that no digit larger than 7 is allowed, in effect making them octal numbers.

And here's a JavaScript implementation

```
function (numberString) {
    var sum = 0;
    var digits = numberString.split('');
    for (var i=0; i < digits.length; i++) {
        var digit = parseInt(digits[i]);
        sum = sum ^ digit;
    }
    return sum;
};
```

My question is: Does this "method"/"system" have a name/history, similar to the Luhn algorithm? (Even though this is far simpler)

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longitudinal_redundancy_check ?
from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Checksum ctrl-f "xor"

Comment: No. It's suppose to calculate a value between 0 and 7 (inclusive).
Given 654 longitude redundancy check gives the checksum 241 (expected 7).
See test case https://gist.github.com/adbre/4cfeca9b70b204c00777